# Get <style> tag css to only operate on siblings and children?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've recently come to prefer resuable UI modules in the form of single .js files, which manipulate the dom using `div.innerText` and so forth. I'm developing a UI framework of sorts [(a new and better one I swear)](https://xkcd.com/927/) and I plan on allowing other devs to write their own modules to extend my framework.

To ensure that two devs' work doesn't interfere with each other, I'm making my modules self-contained. Then,because they are self-contained, I can rapidly and even recursively deploy them in any div on a page; e.g. call `uiElement.deploy(element)` sets up the reusable `uiElement` with the element as a parent, through code like the following:

```
uiElement.deploy=function(root){
 uiElement.div=document.createElement("div");
 uiElement.div.innerHTML=`
  <style>
   button{
    background:red;
   }
  </style>
  <button>Hey!</button>`;
 root.appendChild(uiElement.div);
}
```

It all works pretty well, but when it comes to styling, I'm a bit wary of declaring `<style>` elements in the innerHTML, because they might adversely impact the styling of my other reusable modules.

So, I'm wondering, why hasn't the HTML standard decided that if you put a `<style>` element in a container other than `<head>`, it only operates on the container's children (i.e. ithe `style` tag's siblings) and their decendants? It feels like a good idea to promote code reusability.

And by the way, how might I avoid the problem I've stated above? My current thought is to give the div a unique ID and then edit the css in my `<style>` tag, by parsing the innerHTML with regex.

Comment: for the last question I would suggest also to provide a class name as a function argument and add this to the style block: `button.«classname»`

Comment: Why not style the button with an inline style, solves the issue and saves code

Comment: I don't recognize `.deploy()` method, are you using a framework or did you instantiate a  `class`, use `.prototype`? How is `uiElement` defined?

Comment: Is the question 'why isn't this a standard?'?  Probably because it isn't a standard to have web page contain JavaScript that is responsible for generating the web page, in the same way that it isn't a standard to have a Word document contain a macro that is responsible for generating the Word document.  Maybe try making something _of_ the web, not just something that's _on_ the web.

Comment: Your last incomplete paragraph is heading in the right direction, I think.  CSS specificity, doesn't have to be an ID, just a container that you can classify, the 'class' attribute seems to be a good fit for *class*ification of things...

Comment: There are also IFRAMEs, whilst we're waiting for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM to become something with good support.  These approaches are a LOT of work, I can think of much easier ways of putting red buttons on a page!

Comment: @MatthewPage yeah i forgot to put that in my question :3 I was thinking about inline styles but were concerned that they might slow down the browser - is this the case?

Comment: @zer00ne It's a javascript function/object/class/whatever. It's not a standard API. I'm trying to build my own set of standards, though this does come into mind: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski ok fine 3: The web's branched out not only as a content delivery system but also as an application framework, and I'm trying to capitalise on that. I do love my JS code.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski and on your _class_ification thing, yes i do concede that that would work, but consider the case when uiElement1 and uiElement2 use the same class names and their styling clashes :/ I want to avoid that. Yes it is an unorthodox thing to do but hey it's 2019 :3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188671/discussion-between-thornkey-and-lee-kowalkowski).

Comment: Pah!  If you're generating in JS you can have unique class names!  Flash sites and XHTML were popular once but they're extinct now, I don't think JS-generated websites are all that strong. They're often really buggy and the framework-of-flavour is a shifting landscape, jquery->bootstrap->angular->react->vue(?)...  So if you want to build something that you don't need to rewrite or be obsoleted, don't follow those bandwagons, they're 'branching out', but that's not the web!  I don't mind the unorthodox-ness so much, and JS is my language of choice also, I just don't do any CSS in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS stands for *Cascading Style Sheets*. The *cascading* suggests that it is poured down over every element starting at the root node: `document`. The specification states that any [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)-element always applies to the whole `document`.

My solution to your question of applying a own style to the element. However this solution is not elegant and can be solved better, since it will clutter the document with style-elements whenever an element is added.

```js
uiElement.deploy=function(element, className){
 uiElement.div=document.createElement("div");
 uiElement.div.innerHTML=`
  <style>
   button.${className}{
    background:red;
   }
  </style>
  <button class="${className}">Hey!</button>`;
 element.appendChild(uiElement.div);
}
```

Better would be to add a `link`-element which points to a css-file that has style information about your code.

```
uiElement.deploy=function(element, className){
 uiElement.div=document.createElement("div");
 //link element - if not present in document: add.
 if (!document.querySelector(`link[href='location/${element}.css']`))
 {
     const link = document.createElement("link");
     link.href = `location/${element}.css'`;
     document.head.appendChild(link);
 }
 uiElement.div.innerHTML=`
  <button class="${className}">Hey!</button>`;
 element.appendChild(uiElement.div);
}
```

A stylesheet file (`.css`) also provides easier and more flexible management of your code, not needing to change the js-file if you just want to change the visual appearance.

Even in the situation above I would highly suggest to set a unique ID or class name to your created elements to differ in your CSS-rules, because CSS-rules are valid for the whole document.

Comment: I get the general gist of this answer - but the `element` im passing is a literal DOM element rather than a string (which may not even be attached, maybe created via `document.createElement`) - and because the uiElement can be attached to multiple DOM elements creating one single css file is not enough. I've used another solution (shadow DOM) but im still interested in yours - any thoughts on fixing it?

Comment: Well are the items created styled the same way? If so than you can use `element.nodeName.toLowerCase()` to get the element's name.

Answer (score 1):

Give your outer element an `ID` if it doesn't already have one, (or possibly a `class`),
then you can write your CSS snippet to only apply to the children of that element:
`#thisID button { ... }`

Comment: @Matthew : How so? It doesn't answer the vague bit about "why doesn't CSS already work the way I want it to", but it _does_ explain how to limit the scope of his CSS to the relevant bit of HTML

Comment: If you read the last line he talks about adding an ID. Thought the rules were don't answer badly asked questions. The web site asked me to review your answer so I have, but don't really want to get into a debate about it

Answer (score 0):

I've revisited the problem and would have recommended to my past self: Shadow DOM!

Shadow DOM can give CSS elements scope. The disadvantage is that you cannot access elements from the document using `document.getElementById`, which sadly locks you out of a number of libraries e.g. svg.js.

Here's how to use a shadow root, if you have some DOM element:

```
let el=document.createElement("div");
el.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
let st=document.createElement("style");
st.innerHTML=`
div{
    background:blue;
}
`
el.appendChild(st);
```